# How to import a list of users

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I pulled out a list of users from an organization using advanced find, making sure that **all** the columns were included. I also checked the re-import headers box.

When I imported the list (same server, same AD rights) into another organization, I got no errors, no failures **but** no successes neither. No users were created at all.

Is it an intended behavior or did I forgot something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intended - re-import option breaks the import when not the same organization with the same data.  Re-import option should only be used on the same organization.  You can see from an old blog post from the CRM Team they state to not use that option when moving data org to org.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/03/23/transferring-data-from-one-crm-organization-to-other-organization.aspx

> Note: Do not check make this data available for reimport checkbox as this feature is meant to export and update data in the same organization and not for cross organization data migration.

Re-imports intended use is for mass editing data that is already existing in the system.

Comment: What would be a smart way to **create** a bunch of *User* instances? Preferably including the role settings (not a requirement, though)?

Comment: Do the export / import thing but don't check the box for _re_-import. Assuming the two orgs are in the same domain...

Comment: You can download the import data template and mass create users.  Assigning a security role cannot be handled via the out of the box import.  You could handle via the SDK.  I am unaware of any public utilities for doing such a task though.  Perhaps use a field to tag people as a certain group then you can filter by that field and mass assign them their group through the CRM GUI.

Answer (score 0):

CRM may disable the imported users by default. Check the disabled users view.